# Pushforward and Pullback Applied to Composition of Maps

Tags: differential-geometry, physics, pullback, pushforward

I'm working through Frankel's "The Geometry of Physics" this summer, and I'm stuck on a problem concerning the pushforward and pullback operations.  The problem is stated as follows:

Let $F:M^n \rightarrow W^r$ and $G:W^r \rightarrow V^s$ be smooth maps. Let x, y, and z be local coordinates near $p \epsilon M$. $F(p) \epsilon W$ and $G(F(p)) \epsilon V$, respectively.  We may consider the composite map $G \circ F: M \rightarrow V$.

(i) Show, by using bases $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$, that $$(G \circ F)_* = G_* \circ F_*$$

(ii) Show, by using bases $dx$, $dy$, $dz$, that $$(G \circ F)^* = G^* \circ F^*$$

So far I've started with the fact that: $$(G \circ F)_* = (G_* \circ F) \cdot F_*$$ by the chain rule, but I'm not sure how to proceed.  I feel like if I can get help with the first one the second one shouldn't be much of an issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Actually, your way of writing the chain rule is *correct* and his way (not indicating where things are evaluated) is sloppy. But he just wants you to deduce this from the the chain rule in Euclidean space by using local coordinates, as specified.

Comment: This is true. Maybe another way of writing things down is $(G\circ F)_{*,p}=G_{*,F(p)}\circ F_{*,p}$. In here $F_{*,p}$ is the pushforward acting on $T_pM$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation $(G_\star\circ F)\cdot F_\star$ doesn't make much sense to me. Namely, what is the $\cdot$.

A way to go through this is to compute the coordinate expressions of the pushforward. For a vector $X\in T_p M$ and a function $f\in C^\infty(W)$ we have
$$(F_*X)f:=X(f\circ F).$$
In particular, if $X=X^\mu\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}\right)_p$, we obtain
$$(F_*X)f:=X^\mu\frac{\partial(f\circ F)}{\partial x^\mu}(p):=X^\mu\partial_\mu(f\circ F\circ x^{-1})(x(p))=X^\mu\partial_\mu(f\circ y^{-1}\circ y\circ F\circ x^{-1})(x(p)).$$
Notice that now $f\circ y^{-1}$ is a function defined on an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^r$ and taking values on $\mathbb{R}$. Similarly $y\circ F\circ x^{-1}$ is a function defined on an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and taking values on $\mathbb{R}^r$. We can thus use the usual chain rule of multivariable calculus to obtain
$$(F_*X)f=X^\mu\partial_a(f\circ y^{-1})(y(F(p)))\partial_\mu(y^a\circ F\circ x^{-1})(x(p))=X^\mu\frac{\partial f}{\partial y^a}(F(p))\frac{\partial y^a\circ F}{\partial x^\mu}(p).$$
Notice that in this computation there is a proof for the chain rule on manifolds. Letting $F_{(y)}^a:=y^a\circ F$, then we find the coordinate expression
$$F_*X=X^\mu\frac{\partial F_{(y)}^a}{\partial x^\mu}(p)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^a}\right)_{F(p)}$$
Applying this formula again we have for $Y\in T_{F(p)}M$
$$G_* Y=Y^a\frac{\partial G_{(z)}^A}{\partial y^a}(F(p))\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial z^A}\right)_{G(F(p))}.$$
Putting it all together, we have
$$(G_* \circ F_*)X=X^\mu\frac{\partial F_{(y)}^a}{\partial x^\mu}(p)\frac{\partial G_{(z)}^A}{\partial y^a}(F(p))\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial z^A}\right)_{G(F(p))}=X^\mu\frac{\partial G_{(z)}^A
\circ F}{\partial x^\mu}(p)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial z^A}\right)_{G(F(p))},$$
using our chain rule for manifolds. However, using the coordinate expression of the pushforward but now applied to $G\circ F$ we see that indeed
$$(G\circ F)_*X=(G_* \circ F_*)X.$$

The proof for the pullbacks follows exactly the same reasoning.

May I suggest the lectures of Prof. Schuller https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLPH7f_7ZlzxTi6kS4vCmv4ZKm9u8g5yic ? I found them very helpful. If you would like a more compact version for GR check https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFeEvEPtX_0S6vxxiiNPrJbLu9aK1UVC_ .

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've been watching those lectures, but stopped. I should go back to them!